# Excel Copy Paste Macro Offsetting Incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro to paste values and formatting into another workbook. It mostly works ok but I am having a problem with the lines pasting into Sheet1.

Instead of pasting the values, formatting and then resizing the font the code pastes the values then on the next blank row pastes the formatting then on the next blank row resizes the font.

I want the values, formatting and font resize to work on the same rows.

The macro runs from a button. A user will select options then click the button to run it multiple times. The idea is that Sheet1 will have a list of multiple entries.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
    Sub CreateNewSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

    With Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Worksheets.Add()
    .Name = Range("E3").Value
    End With

Sheets("Summary").Range("A22:J63").Copy
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A:J").Font.Size = 10

Sheets("Summary").Range("A22:J27").Copy
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Font.Size = 10

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you offset 3 times. And the last row changes in between your offsets because you added one row of data.

```
With Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Font.Size = 10
End With
```

This will offset only once and perform all three actions on the same cell.

Alternatively you can use a variable and use this instead of a `With` statement:

```
Dim MyDestination As Range
Set MyDestination = Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

MyDestination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
MyDestination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
MyDestination.Font.Size = 10
```

Note if you have to write the same code twice you should think about it. Either use a variabe or a with statement then. If it is a block that repeats then using procedures/functions (that can be re-used) might be a good idea. Repeating code is bad code in most cases.

Comment: Hi Peh, thanks for this. I get a Pastespecial method of Range class failed" error on this line: .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: @rob Did you copy something right before? Looks like you didn't. Checkout this too: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/2/26/caution-creating-creating-pastespecial-macros

Comment: Thanks Peh. Got it fixed